# What does 400 Bad Request invalid_request mean when creating a Sonos API oauth Token

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, sonos

When I post to https://api.sonos.com/login/v3/oauth/access I get a 400 error with a message `invalid_request`

1. Endpoint added to the portal: [image: Endpoint added to the portal]
2. I send a `GET`<sup>1</sup> to `/login/v3/oauth` and get an authorization code after going through the Sonos login process.
3. I POST to `login/v3/oauth/access`<sup>2</sup> and at that point I get error 400 Bad Request with message invalid_request. This isn't a valid response according to the docs, as these are the responses that can be returned:

   - 401 Unauthorized: invalid_request
   - 400 Bad Request:  invalid_client
   - 400 Bad Request:  invalid_redirect_uri
   - 400 Bad Request:  invalid_code
   - 405 Method Not Allowed: invalid_method

What does this response mean? Hopefully with some additional info I can work out what I'm doing wrong, but you can see the code [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sapphire-tadpole?path=server.js). I'm using the `simple-oauth2` library, but I've tried a few different ways with the same result so I guess I'm doing something fundamentally wrong!

Here's the curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" \
-H "Authorization: Basic MThhYjU4MjYtOTYzNy00YjFiLTlmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtNGUzOC1iMGUwLTZiMDA4N2ZiMDM0Yw==" \
"https://api.sonos.com/login/v3/oauth/access" \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=aba2cc0c-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX998d599&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsapphire-tadpole.glitch.me%2Ffinally" -v
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 2.22.97.140...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.sonos.com (2.22.97.140) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Santa Barbara; O=Sonos, Inc.; OU=IT; CN=*.sonos.com
*  start date: Mar  9 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 12 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.sonos.com" matched cert's "*.sonos.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /login/v3/oauth/access HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.sonos.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8
> Authorization: Basic MThhYjU4MjYtOTYzNy00YjFiLTlmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXtNGUzOC1iMGUwLTZiMDA4N2ZiMDM0Yw==
> Content-Length: 135
>
* upload completely sent off: 135 out of 135 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< X-Application-Context: login-service:prod
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Content-Length: 27
< Expires: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 19:50:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Tue, 11 Sep 2018 19:50:00 GMT
< Connection: close
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DB3B48F621A41F0A24E2D6FC2DDE020B; Path=/login/v3; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: AWSELB=69BFEFC914A689BF6DC8E4652748D7B501ED60290D9A5E5030A81F5A29357C8E67353A664FEE6C6D907213C0B2ECB35914CC85B8E047283F4361C4FC809EB10CE87CE95377;PATH=/;MAX-AGE=1800
<
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{"error":"invalid_request"}%
```

<sup>1</sup> [This page](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/) says it should be a `POST` but I think that's a typo?

<sup>2</sup> [This page](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-token/) says it should be sent to `/auth/oauth/v2/access` but I think that's depreciated.

Comment: Can you post the full POST request to the access endpoint so we can review? And thanks for pointing out the docs typos. We'll get those corrected. Of course, mask any sensitive keys.

Comment: @MattWelch done, thank you. Is there another channel for reporting typos etc?

Comment: That all looks correct. Can you confirm that the redirect uri you're supplied in that POST to the /access endpoint exactly matches the one you supplied when you created the control integration on our developer portal. You'd expect us to return an invalid_redirect_url if that were the problem, but let's start there.

Comment: @MattWelch I have already added the redirect uri to the portal. It looks correct? I've added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using the same redirect uri for both the auth code GET and the access token POST?

Comment: @MattWelch doh. I didn't realise you had to do that! That solved it!

Comment: Great. I'll provide an answer. Please mark it as correct for future devs who search. Thanks

Comment: @MattWelch omg, it's even in the docs twice. So sorry! https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-token/ "URI of the site that requested the authorization code. URI of the site that requested the authorization code"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that your redirect uri is correct, and is the same for both the auth code GET and the access token POST.